# round() function not working for databricks-Python

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to use the round() function in databricks to round some float values to 2 digits. However, the databricks python is not working like normal python.

Please help me with the reasons and solutions if any.

```
lis = [-12.1334, 12.23433, 1.2343, -104.444]
lis2 = [round(val,2)  for val in lis]
print(lis2)
```

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: -12.1334 of type <type 'float'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

[Image Proof of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlHqb.png)

Comment: This code does not produce the claimed error.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Can't recreate the error either

Comment: added image proof for convenience

Comment: Also, code must be run in a databricks notebook as opposed to normal python way. The normal python way will run without any error. The problem is for databricks based python.

Answer (score 6):

This is only reproducible when you import the spark round function from the `function` module in spark.sql

The spark round function requires a string or a column. Which explains the error.

You can either alias the import such as `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` instead of `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

You can get the origin `round` method this way.

```
import builtins
round = getattr(builtins, "round")
```

And then you can execute

```
lis = [-12.1334, 12.23433, 1.2343, -104.444]
lis2 = [round(val, 2) for val in lis]
print(lis2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Good day, The question is most likely with name-space conflict. I ran ran something like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Which contains function **round**. You can easily see which round is in usage by running help on it:

```
help(round)
```

Easy fix for this is to designate pyspark function to different name-space.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
lis = [-12.1334, 12.23433, 1.2343, -104.444]
lis2 = [round(val,2)  for val in lis]
print(lis2)

[-12.13, 12.23, 1.23, -104.44]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lis = [-12.1334, 12.23433, 1.2343, -104.444]
list_em = []
for row in lis:
    list_em.append(round(row,2))
print(list_em)

[-12.13, 12.23, 1.23, -104.44]
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem at all. The code OP posted doesn't even have a replicable problem.

Comment: This is not working also. When I run in the databricks notebook the round function is not working. You can check the image proof attached.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the source code for the function you are applying:

```
def round(col, scale=0):
    """
    Round the given value to `scale` decimal places using HALF_UP rounding mode if `scale` >= 0
    or at integral part when `scale` < 0.

    >>> spark.createDataFrame([(2.5,)], ['a']).select(round('a', 0).alias('r')).collect()
    [Row(r=3.0)]
    """
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.round(_to_java_column(col), scale))
```

Clearly it says to pass in a column, not a decimal number. Did you import *? That could have overridden the builtin function.

Comment: Yes. I have removed the all import of spark stuff. Now its working. It was a problem of round function being overridden. Thank you.